# Undefined reference to 'powerOfThree'

Tags: c

I keep on getting the error of `Undefined reference to 'powerOfThree'`.  The `powerOfThree` is my recursive method as you can see below.  Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int powerOfThree(int);

int main(void){

    int userInput;
    printf("PLease enter a number: "); //asking the user to enter a value
    scanf("%d", &userInput); //store that value into userInput
    printf("the value of %d three to the power is: %d", userInput, powerOfThree(userInput)); //passing the value of userInput into powerOfThree.

int powerOfThree(int n) { //recursion method

    if(n<1) {
        return 1; //control 
    } 
    else {
        return (3*powerOfThree(n-1)); //actual calculation
    }
}
return (0);
```

I ask the user to enter a number and store it in the `userInput`. In theory I can pass that input to the recursion method.

Comment: Your implementation of `powerOfThree` should be outside your main function.

Comment: Please format your code and make sure to use appropriate white space to make it readable.  For example, add tabs as necessary to show scope.

Comment: The indentation here is quite chaotic, and parts of the code appear to be missing or really badly formatted. Declare functions prior to use. `main` is generally the last thing in your file.

Comment: This is a mess. Your powerOfThree function is inside your main

Answer (score 5):

GCC is a menace on occasion.

It allows you to define functions inside other functions — nested functions.  You have (presumably accidentally and unintentionally) nested your `powerOfThree()` function inside `main()`.  If you move the `return 0;` before the start of `powerOfThree()` and add the missing close brace, then things will work sanely.

I think that nested functions must be defined before they're used.  See the GCC manual on [nested functions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-8.2.0/gcc/Nested-Functions.html#Nested-Functions) — which does allow a declaration using `auto` if you must declare it before you define it.  As it stands, the compiler assumes you meant to call the non-nested version of the function declared before `main()`.  I recommend against using the GCC-only feature (nested functions).

```
#include <stdio.h>

static int powerOfThree(int);

int main(void)
{
    int userInput;
    printf("Please enter a number: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &userInput) == 1 && userInput >= 0)
    {
        printf("The value of 3 to the power %d is: %d\n",
               userInput, powerOfThree(userInput));
    }
    return (0);
}

static int powerOfThree(int n)
{
    if (n < 1)
        return 1; 
    else
        return (3 * powerOfThree(n-1));
}
```